# Can you have a sentence without a verb?

Tags: ellipsis, headlinese

Where is the verb in this sentence below?

> No Small Business Brands On YouTube

[image]

Does this sentence mean "There are no small business brands on YouTube"? If so, then why does the sentence "No smoking" mean "Don't smoke"?

Comment: It's not a sentence, it's a headline.

Comment: As it stands, it's ambiguous, as deleted forms often are. It might mean 'There are no small business brands on YouTube' or 'Keep small business brands off YouTube'.

Comment: `Brands` _could_ be the verb, but it would make the sentence quite difficult to understand.

Comment: “No smoking” is not a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question. The first one appear to be more a headline, as in "No Clouds in the Sky". It appears the first phrase is pointing out something rather instantaneously, omitting the words "there are". Another example would be someone on a bicycle saying "Look, no hands!".
   The imperative, though, is likely used in all languages, making "Go!" the shortest sentence.

Comment: An imperative is a verbal form. There is no explicit imperative in the OP's sentence, but looking at the "NO" symbol at the left of the image, I think that the sentence has an imperative meaning, like "Small business brands are not allowed on YouTube".